# Android display @ sign with phone soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to make an a soft keyboard which an `EditText` presents have a layout of a phone keyboard but also with a "." and "@" signs.

What I tried was this on the edit text:

```
android:inputType="textEmailAddress|phone"
android:digits="0123456789.@"
```

I'm seeing the keyboard like I want as a phone layout in general and with the "." symbol but without the "@" symbol.. how can I add it to the keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to make an a soft keyboard which an EditText presents have a layout of a phone keyboard but also with a "." and "@" signs.

There is nothing in the specifications that supports this.

```
android:inputType="textEmailAddress|phone"
```

Quoting [the documentation for `android:inputType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType): "Generally you can select a single value, though some can be combined together as indicated." The docs do not suggest that `textEmailAddress` can be combined with `phone`.

```
android:digits="0123456789.@"
```

This stipulates what characters are *allowed*. I am not aware that an `InputMethod` even finds out about this attribute; one certainly does not have to somehow magically adjust its keyboard layout to accommodate it.

> how can I add it to the keyboard?

You don't, except perhaps by writing your own `InputMethod`, then forcing people at gunpoint to use it.

Please understand that there are over 8,000 Android device models. Dozens, if not hundreds, of input methods will be shipped on these devices, and others can be installed by users separately. These are written by independent developers. There is no requirement for any of them to even have keys, as evidenced by [Graffiti Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.access_company.graffiti_pro). And they certainly do not have to handle some arbitrary set of keys that an app developer wants.

`android:inputType` gives you a chance to supply a hint to the input method for how it should optimize the layout for the user. `android:inputType` specifically limits things to a few classes to keep things sane for the developers of the input methods. Furthermore, `android:inputType` is a *hint*, not a demand; as Graffiti Pro illustrates, not all input methods will necessarily change based upon `android:inputType`, at least for all possible types.

Comment: Can't I somehow choose what set of characters are to be shown at the keyboard?

Comment: @JJAb: No, sorry. You are welcome to specify an `android:inputType`. That does not handle arbitrary combinations of characters. It also does not have to be honored by any input method.

Comment: but I can create an input type that will be used inside my own application right?

Comment: @JJAb: The valid values for `android:inputType` are defined in the framework. You cannot change those. You can create your own input method, but that is for the *device*, not merely for your app. As a result, few users will use that input method, because there are security concerns with allowing apps to monitor all text entry, and users may not see value in using your input method.

Comment: so I can't do what I want even if I try and develop it myself.. that's a bummer. Thank you for your help